# Ways to execute DDL statements dynamically while limiting user permissions

Tags: database, postgresql, asp.net-core

So I am trying to develop a web application using .NET Core 2 with a PostgreSQL database, and I need to be able to record a tremendous amount of data. Previously I was using dynamically generated statements to perform DDL operations on the database. An example with dynamic elements in bold:

> DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ BEGIN IF (SELECT to_regclass('public.item[**unique number**]')) IS NULL THEN CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item[**unique number**] (signature character varying(50),itemname character varying(50)...etc

Each table contains approximately 50 columns with certain parameters. Each item table contains multiple dynamic rows of item types, with their own column values.

The problem is that I feel like dynamic statement generation like this is a gaping security flaw. Maybe I'm wrong, but it feels that way.

I have come up with two alternatives:

1) Create 50 tables representing the former columns of each table and then INSERT across all 50, and JOIN for all during SELECT statements. (My concern is how this would affect performance compared to simply selecting all from 1 table. I am also concerned that if one of these tables is corrupted/etc it will affect many items whereas in the old way a corrupted table would only affect 1 item.)

2) Pre-generate a tremendous number of empty tables and then INSERT records into each empty table as needed while keeping track of the table names in another table. Perhaps a stored procedure could periodically generate more if needed. (This feels like a hack to me.)

Does anyone have suggestions for how to store this data while avoiding dynamic DDL statements being sent by the client?

Answer (score 0):

you can save plpgsql to function instead and accept argumets. also you can use `format` to avoid injection, lastly you can check if such column exists, eg:

```
t=# create or replace function ct(_n text) returns void as $$
begin
select attname into _n from pg_attribute where attname = _n;
if _n is not null then
  execute format('create table if not exists %I()','item'||_n);
end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

now:

```
t=# select ct(e'\';--hack');
 ct
----

(1 row)

Time: 2.202 ms
t=# \dt item*
No matching relations found.
```

and if column is valid:

```
t=# select ct('a');
 ct
----

(1 row)

t=# \dt item*
       List of relations
 Schema | Name  | Type  | Owner
--------+-------+-------+-------
 public | itema | table | vao
(1 row)
```